# /opt/homebrew/bin/spark-submit: line 27: /bin/spark-class: No such file or directory

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, homebrew

I am using homebrew and I have installed spark using

```
brew install apache-spark
```

I have also checked the path

```
echo $PATH
```

and it looks like

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/homebrew/bin
```

I have also tried to start the pyspark shell as

```
pyspark --master local[2]
```

but the same error comes.

Comment: Submit this as a packaging bug to Homebrew. Stack Overflow isn't the right place for it -- we aren't the people positioned to fix the problem. (If it's a missing dependency, f/e, then the package can be amended to require it explicitly).

Comment: Do you even really need homebrew? `pip install pyspark` should just work... https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/install.html

Comment: thanks @OneCricketeer i thought i had installed this already.

Comment: Pip doesn't use Homebrew to install things, so they'd be separate installations (and maybe versions)